# MySQL Insert tables

Tags: mysql, database

My main *local* MySQL data base is designed this way **Table A**

```
ID | NAME | PHONE
 1 | Jhon | 555
 2 | Carl | 666
```

where ID is the KEY auto incremental. Furthermore I have also a *remote* SQLite data.db file which I have to download every month to convert it to MySQL. The result table looks like this **Table B**

```
NAME | PHONE
Phil | 777
Ben  | 888
```

Because **Table A** doesn't have the same structure as **Table B** I am not able to join them. Is there a way to insert (import?) *Table B* into *Table A* using the auto increment?. like this

```
ID | NAME | PHONE
 1 | Jhon | 555
 2 | Carl | 666
 3 | Phil | 777
 4 | Ben  | 888
```

An additional question: If I install MySQL instead of SQLite in the *remote* Linux can I remotely connect both databases and keep **Table A** always updated? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Of course you can `JOIN` it, just use the `NAME` column...?

Comment: I think it is not related to JOIN. It is related to UNION

Comment: I edited my question. I need to actual Insert Table B into Table A. So I will have, as a result, a bigger Table A.

Answer (score 0):

So what I did was to edit the dump.sql from **Table B** file and add the name of the of the columns like this

```
INSERT INTO Column1 (NAME, PHONE) VALUES ('Phil','777');
INSERT INTO Column1 (NAME, PHONE) VALUES ('Benn','888');
```

for then to run

```
mysql -u root -p TableA < dump.sql
```

though, can I actually do it directly without the dump?

Comment: If it's short term, just do what works.  If it's long term, redesign the DB that you can change so it fits.

Comment: how? I am planing to have one big local Table A being fed by many remote Tables B. As table A will have auto_incremental ID, how can I make this work?